# In Excel how can I replace the text from one cell into another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have in Column A a list of 20 cars.

In column B I have a long description of cars and I need to put the list from Column A into the description in column B.

For example.

Cell A1
Chevy

Cell B1  This [car] is a great car.  Everyone who has a [car] loves it.   Our experts think the [car] is a great choice.................

I would like for it to read:

This Chevy is a great car.  Everyone who has a Chevy loves it.   Our experts think the Chevy is a great choice.................

My question is how can I replace [car] with chevy and so forth as I have many to do, and then in cell B1 I need to replace it many times.

Thanks.

Comment: Use the [SUBSTITUTE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/substitute-function-2bdd8fb3-d756-4656-8aa4-e871e6578671).

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B1,"[car]",A1)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SUBSTITUTE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/substitute-function-2bdd8fb3-d756-4656-8aa4-e871e6578671).

```
=SUBSTITUTE("This [car] is a great car. Everyone who has a [car] loves it.", "[car]", A1)
```

[image: sub stitute_car]